# Using Spring Batch with MariaDB giving error

Tags: java, mariadb, spring-batch

I have a small Batch application. If I run it with H2 Database it works fine however when I use my actual database it gave error.

The Application.java file shown below

```
@SpringBootApplication()
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FaxProcesser35Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting the job");
    }
}
```

The reason why I am using `CommandLineRunner` is because without it the job was not running.

The code of JobConfig.java is given below

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;



    @Bean
    public Tasklet myTasklet() {
        System.out.println("tasklet method was called");
        return new MyTasklet() ;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step myStep(JobRepository jobRepository, Tasklet myTasklet, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("myStep", jobRepository)
                .tasklet(myTasklet, transactionManager) // or .chunk(chunkSize, transactionManager)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job myJob() {
        System.out.println("Job Method was called");
        return new JobBuilder("myJob", jobRepository)
                .start(myStep(jobRepository, myTasklet(), transactionManager))
                .build();
    }

    private class MyTasklet implements Tasklet {
        @Override
        public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution  stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Running MyTasklet");
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }
    }
}
```

The application.properties files is list as below

```
#--------------------- DB Connection ------------------
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/database

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

At first it said unable to find tables. So I create the tables by manually running [this script](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mariadb.sql)

However now its giving error `Could not increment ID for BATCH_JOB_SEQ sequence table` and `Unknown column 'ID' in 'field list'`

I ran `describe BATCH_JOB_SEQ ;` got following response

```
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| next_not_cached_value | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| minimum_value         | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| maximum_value         | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| start_value           | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| increment             | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cache_size            | bigint(21) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cycle_option          | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cycle_count           | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.017 sec)
```

The complete error is given below

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.ahmadiyya.LetterTohazoor.faxprocesser35.FaxProcesser35Application.main(FaxProcesser35Application.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not increment ID for BATCH_JOB_SEQ sequence table
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.java:153) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.nextLongValue(AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.java:128) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:110) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:168) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:207) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy68.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:145) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher.run(TaskExecutorJobLauncher.java:70) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:178) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:166) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:161) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:156) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:760) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'ID' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1334) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2084) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1245) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyStatement.java:119) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.java:148) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Either your new DB table does not have an id column, or id column named as the id in the query (or both). It potentially should be an Auto increment id system depending how row id's are created. The entity id for the query may not match either.

Comment: Which MariaDB version do you use? We have a test that validates the DDL schema that you shared and it passes with MariaDB 10.9.3, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/core/test/repository/MariaDBJobRepositoryIntegrationTests.java.

Comment: I am using version 10.11.1-MariaDB. I can try installing 10.9.3 and let you know the results.

Comment: The test I shared passes with MariaDB 10.11.2. So please provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I have updated the question with example. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue, see complete example here: https://github.com/fmbenhassine/spring-batch-lab/tree/main/issues/so75903185.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a column named ID, which is logged here

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'ID' in 'field list'

I could not find any column named ID in the script. Maybe let Hibernate generate the Batch Tables with this property in your application.properties

> spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=ALWAYS